# How can I run a full flow in Google Cloud Dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Cloud Dataprep. I can a run a single recipe, but I would like to run a full job composed by several recipes. I know that I can schedule, but is ther any option to 'run flow' right now?

Also, I would like to know if I can change the output of a recipe and write in  outputs different from a csv, for example I would like to write in a Google Big Query table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are in the Flows screen that shows all of your flows, or if you are in the flow overview screen, you can click on the ellipse (...) and schedule the flow. This requires that you schedule it for multiple runs and does NOT have a one time / ad-hoc option. You could schedule it then delete the schedule once it runs once.

If the recipes are dependent on one another, then when you run the job tied to the recipe at the end of the flow, it should execute the preceding recipes.

Beyond that, this appears to be a functional gap in the dataprep tool. Its means to be more of an end-user friendly tool than a full blown automation tool. For the more technically savvy its probably worth investigating if you can accomplish what you need to do in dataflow.

Here's a related stackoverflow thread that provides additional detail on the last option:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224329/how-do-i-chain-multiple-google-cloud-dataprep-flows

Answer (score 0):

I am using the new flow view which is in beta. I click on the output, and I get the button "Run job", which runs the flow ad hoc.

[image]